# Apache FOP does not honor font settings/directory for DocBook

Tags: apache-http-server, fonts, docbook, fop

I'm trying to use Microsoft's Arial Unicode font in a DocBook project. The project is using [Apache's FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/). FOP is installed in `/usr/local/bin/fop-1.1`.

The `Arial_Unicode.ttf` font is installed in `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/`:

```
$ ls -l /usr/share/fonts/truetype/
total 22812
drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root      4096 Oct 22 11:43 abyssinica
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root  23278008 Oct  8  2013 Arial_Unicode.ttf
drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root      4096 Nov  7 12:02 dejavu
...
```

FOP's configuration file is located at:

```
$ find /usr/local/bin/fop-1.1/ -iname *.xconf
/usr/local/bin/fop-1.1/conf/fop.xconf
```

I opened `fop.xconf` and added two `directory` elements and `auto-detect` element under `renderer` for `mime="application/pdf"` per Apache's [Bulk Font Configuration](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/fonts.html):

```
  <renderers>
    <renderer mime="application/pdf">
      <filterList>
        ...
      </filterList>

      <fonts>
        <directory recursive="true">/usr/share/fonts</directory>
        <directory recursive="true">/usr/share/fonts/truetype</directory>

        <!-- automatically detect operating system installed fonts -->
        <auto-detect/>

        ...
      </fonts>
    ...
```

When I build my book, nearly all the glyphs are `#`:

[image]

When using a different Object Processor (such as [RenderX's xep](http://www.renderx.com/tools/xep.html)), the document renders. So I believe the DocBook XML is good (specifically, the custom translation that uses `Arial_Unicode.ttf`).

How do I make Apache FOP honor its configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the Arial font explicitly in the configuration file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<fop>
    <renderers>
        <renderer mime="application/pdf">       
          <fonts>                           
                <font kerning="yes" embed-url="file:///C:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf">
                      <font-triplet name="Arial" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
                </font>                     
          </fonts>
        </renderer>
    </renderers>     
</fop>
```